# How to make image hover in css?

Tags: css, image, hover

I want to change the image from normal to brighter when it's on hover, My code:

```
    <div class="nkhome">
        <a href="Home.html"><img src="Images/btnhome.png" /></a>
    </div>
.nkhome{
    margin-left:260px;
    top:170px;
    position:absolute;
    width:59px;
    height:59px;
}
.nkhome a img:hover {
    background:url(Images/btnhomeh.png);
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
```

Why doesn't work the hover? When my mouse is on it, it shows the first image, not the hover image.

Comment: it's solve, just changing background to background image and then set the width and height

Comment: here are some links that i have i have found, really easy to put some cool effects using CSS3, for such a thing: http://designshack.net/?p=19746 http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/ they have copy paste code, easy to follow.

Comment: HERE http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp
set the opacity

Comment: Find a simple solution with samples with four color hover effect for a menu with percentage timing - demo in http://tinkumax.blogspot.com/2012/11/simple-css3-hover-transition-menu-effect.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've got an `a` tag containing an `img` tag. That's your normal state.
You then add a `background-image` as your hover state, and it's appearing in the background of your `a` tag - behind the `img` tag.

You should probably create a CSS sprite and use background positions, but this should get you started:

```
<div>
    <a href="home.html"></a>
</div>

div a {
    width:  59px;
    height: 59px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url('images/btnhome.png');
}

div a:hover {
    background-image: url('images/btnhomeh.png);
}
```

This [A List Apart Article from 2004](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) is still relevant, and will give you some background about sprites, and why it's a good idea to use them instead of two different images. It's a lot better written than anything I could explain to you.

Comment: You'll only need to set the width/height in the original style for the hyperlink, the styles are carried through to the hover pseudo class unless you manually override them :)

Comment: But this solution, although technically good, is inaccessible. There's a link (a) without text.

Comment: @gulima that's correct. While the question (and therefore the solution) are not inclusive of everything one would do in good web practice the easiest way to do this is to add a text-indent similar to the one [Jeffrey Zeldman proposes](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/).

Answer (score 8):

Simply this, no extra div or JavaScript needed, just pure CSS ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LMFWG/1/)):

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Hello!')" class="changesImgOnHover">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x25/00f/ff0.png&text=Hello!" alt="Hello!">
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.changesImgOnHover {
    display: inline-block; /* or just block */
    width: 50px;
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/50x25/0f0/f00.png&text=Hello!') no-repeat;
}
.changesImgOnHover:hover img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Clever. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: update 2019:  a variant, perhaps a bit more modern with a sprite in the background instead of an image inside the anchor [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scrypter/wa3nrm8f/)

Answer (score 7):

You're setting the background of the image to another image.  Which is fine, but the foreground (SRC attribute of the IMG) still overlays everything else.

```
.nkhome{
    margin-left:260px;
    top:170px;
    position:absolute;
}
.nkhome a {
    background:url(Images/btnhome.png);
    display:block; /* Necessary, since A is not a block element */
    width:59px;
    height:59px;
}
.nkhome a:hover {
    background:url(Images/btnhomeh.png);
}


<div class="nkhome">
    <a href="Home.html"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for sportsmanship and bothering to copy out everything (and remembering display: block like I forgot!)

Comment: @greenthunder - That's because I made a typo.  backogrund isn't a CSS attribute.  : )  Props to djlumley's answer.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work like this, put both images as background images:

```
.bg-img {
    background:url(images/yourImg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.bg-img:hover {
    background:url(images/yourImg-1.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you should give parent position relative and child absolute and give to height or width to absolute class as like this

**Css**

```
  .nkhome{
    margin-left:260px;
    width:59px;
    height:59px;
    margin-top:170px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
.nkhome a:hover img{
    opacity:0.0;
}
.nkhome a:hover{
  background:url('http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg');
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;

}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="nkhome">
        <a href="Home.html"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
​
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/t5FEX/7/

---

or this

```
<div class="nkhome">
        <a href="Home.html"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg'" 
            onmouseout="this.src='http://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff.jpg'"
            /></a>
    </div>​
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/t5FEX/9/

Answer (score 1):

**Exact solution to your problem**

You can change the image on hover by using **content:url("YOUR-IMAGE-PATH")**;

For image hover use below line in your css:

```
img:hover
```

and to change the image on hover using the below config inside img:hover:

```
img:hover{
content:url("https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/9-credit-1.jpg");
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant! By far the best option if you're reading this after 2017 :) In my particular case, I just wish to *add* this feature to *existing* CSS (more precisely, WordPress themes); the other solutions, while very likely more compatible with ancient browsers, requires many more changes... Also note that you can add additional special effects as well, besides changing the image, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some easy to folow steps and a great on hover tutorial its the examples that you can "play" with and test live.

http://fivera.net/simple-cool-live-examples-image-hover-css-effect/

Answer (score -1):

Make on class with this. And make 2 different images with the self width and height.  Works in ie9.

See this link.

http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/pure-css-image-hover/

Also you can 2 differents images make and place in the self class name with in the hover the another images.

See example.

```
 .myButtonLink {
              margin-top: -5px;

    display: block;
    width: 45px;
    height: 39px;
    background: url('images/home1.png') bottom;
    text-indent: -99999px;
              margin-left:-17px;

              margin-right:-17px;

              margin-bottom: -5px;

              border-radius: 3px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 3px;           
}

.myButtonLink:hover {
    margin-top:  -5px;

    display: block;
    width: 45px;
    height: 39px;
              background: url('images/home2.png') bottom;
              text-indent: -99999px;
              margin-left:-17px;

              margin-right:-17px;

              margin-bottom: -20x;

              border-radius: 3px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
```