# Changing image on hover with css

Tags: html, css

[image]

I dont know much about css but what can i do to change the bullet image on the submenus?

```
#leftCntr .menuBox ul li a { padding: 0px 0px 0px 54px; color: #7d9696; text-decoration: none; background: url(../images/menuDisc.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat; }
        #leftCntr .menuBox ul li a.active { color: #949494; background: url(../images/menuDiscHover.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat; }
        #leftCntr .menuBox ul li a:hover { color: #000000; background: url(../images/menuDiscHover.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Please show in jsfiddle. You should show HTML too...!

Comment: look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202641/how-to-make-image-hover-in-css

Comment: I don't know much about your HTML, but you could try setting them to a different URL.

Comment: If you have URL ... Please provide..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing your HTML code, but I'm guessing something like this should do:

```
#leftCntr .menuBox ul li a {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 54px;
    color: #7d9696;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(../images/menuDisc.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat;
}

#leftCntr .menuBox ul li a.active {
    color: #949494;
    background: url(../images/menuDiscHover.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat;
}

#leftCntr .menuBox ul li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background: url(../images/menuDiscHover.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat;
}

#leftCntr .menuBox ul li li a {
    background: url(../images/submenuDisc.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat; /* Set the image here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your css.
It will remove the background from li's that are within another list.

You can of course also just set a different background if you want a different image to show.

```
#leftCntr .menuBox ul li ul li a:active {
    background: none;
}

#leftCntr .menuBox ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

(Edited to match the A element.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
#leftCntr .menuBox ul li a { padding: 0px 0px 0px 54px; color: #7d9696; text-decoration: none; background: url(../images/menuDisc.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat; }
        #leftCntr .menuBox ul li a.active { color: #949494; background: url(../images/menuDiscHover.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat; }
        #leftCntr .menuBox ul li a:hover { color: #000000; background: url(../images/menuDiscHover.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat; }

/* New Added */

 #leftCntr .menuBox ul li li a.active { color: #949494; background: url(../images/menuDiscHover.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat; }
            #leftCntr .menuBox ul li li a:hover { color: #000000; background: url(../images/menuDiscHover.gif) 10px 4px no-repeat; }
```