# change image link when hover the link css

Tags: css, image, hyperlink

I have this link :

```
<a href = "" ><img src="images_cartographie/cartographie3_05.gif" width="207" height="47" alt=""></a></td>
```

and I  want to change the image when the user over the link I tested :

```
#planification:hover{
background-image:"images_cartographie/cartographie3_03.gif";
}
```

but the image doesn't change, it is ignored, (I tested background-color it works (then the problem isn't in url or ...))

when I use the background-image without hover like that : 
it doesn't appear :

```
#planification{
background-image:"images_cartographie/cartographie3_03.gif";
}
```

NB : I generated the page with photoshop

do you have any idea

Comment: use background-image on both `#planification:{background-image:}` and `#planification:hover:{background-image:}`

Comment: remove `src` from `img`....

Comment: [How to make image hover in css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202641/how-to-make-image-hover-in-css).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can completely remove the `img` because you add the efect via **CSS** on the `a` tag.

**HTML**

```
<a href="" class="image_link"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.image_link{
    display:block;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    background:url('http://ferringtonpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Responsibilities-of-Owning-a-New-Puppy-Photo-by-bestdogsforkids.jpg');
}

.image_link:hover {
    display:block;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    background:url('http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m4frqhdW0k1rwpusuo1_1280.jpg');
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKMpb/55/).

Note that you must add `dispay:block/inline-block` to the `a`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about your question, but it sounds like you need to put in two different images. So, there's one image when you mouse over, and another image when you don't.  You just put in a different path for the background-url on hover.  Also, you should put in a plank gif in your img tag for backwards compatibility.

You should also use a self closing tag /> for your image. The tag is open the way that you posted it.

```
#planification
{
    background: url(images_cartographie/cartographie3_03.gif) 
}

#planification:hover
{
    background: url(images_cartographie/new_image_goes_here.gif) 
}

<a id="planification" href = "" ><img src="images_cartographie/blank.gif" width="207" height="47" alt=""/></a>
```